# Create hash for array irrespective of element order

Tags: php, arrays, hash

If I have an array with two elements that I want to sha1 hash, what would be the best way to hash irrespective of the order of the elements. This problem also applies for larger arrays and multidimensional arrays.

So `[a=1,b=2]` and `[b=2,a=1]` will return the same hash.

node.js has [Object-Hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash) that does exactly this for example.

Comment: How exactly are you going to use sha1 on that? Perhaps sorting the array would give you what you need.

Comment: Barmar's answer is correct; you should accept it in order to mark the question as being solved; it helps everyone including yourself.

Comment: @Qirel am curious why you rejected the edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15986022 *"This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question."* - Both suggested tags fit the question, IMHO.

Comment: @Fred -ii- why are you telling me to accept an answer so soon. I only just woke up. Im confused to what im doing wrong to warrent such basic advice?

Comment: oh; so you're the type who posts an answer and leaves, 10-4. Only to find an answer that doesn't seem to fit the bill. You were asked another question by someone else but failed to answer them; just me.

Comment: @Qirel I'm going to serialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array by keys, then serialize it, then hash that.

```
ksort($array);
$hash = sha1(serialize($array));
```

Comment: I've thought about sorting but wasn't sure about the reliability. I'd be interested if Object-Sort from nodejs does this same approach though

Comment: It looks like it does. The source code is [here](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/blob/master/index.js). See line 219 where it does `var keys = Object.keys(object).sort();`